# Where does the form submit to if there is no action specified?

Tags: php, forms

Here is the form that is confusing me

```
<h1>
    Login
</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember">
                <font size="2">
                    Remember me next time
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="sublogin" value="Login">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <a href="register.php">Join</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I got the code from this [tutorial](http://evolt.org/node/60265/) and it works fine but i cant seem to understand where a/the form submit too if no action is present

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If `action` is set to `""` or if the `action` attribute is missing, the form submits to itself. That is, if your script is `index.php`, your form submits to `index.php`.

Comment: Because it's treated as the relative path "", which expands to the current absolute path.

Answer (score 17):

If the form's action attribute is either set to `""` **OR** not specified, it will still default to `action="self"`, thus the form will send to the address of the document containing the form.

So,

```
<form method="post">

<!-- IS THE SAME AS... -->

<form action="" method="post">

<!-- IS THE SAME AS... -->

<form action="self" method="post">
```

(Try it)

#### For reference, see the HTML standard 4.10.18.3 #8:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm

Comment: `action="self"` submits to **/self** which is wrong.  Tested this to be sure and it does **not** do the same thing as empty attribute.  Searched specs and see no mention of "self" in this context

Comment: I believe he was just using "self" as an explanation, not an example.

Answer (score 7):

default action for form submission is METHOD="GET" and ACTION="SELF"
*you should use a form name*

if the action is empty then it posts to itself.

Comment: does that mean if you go <form method="post"> instead of <form action="" method="post"> (leaving out action entirely) it still posts to itself? or does this just work in some browsers.

Comment: @robertking, see my answer for this, including examples and a reference to the HTML standard.

Comment: another person posting about how `ACTION="SELF"` submits to self.. where are you guys getting this from?  That's not how it works.  I know this is 6 years old but I don't think it worked like that 6 years ago either.