# jquery click function is responding weirdly. ajax call also not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Instead of a `POST` request, somehow `GET` is being triggered.

Secondly, the ajax call is not being called.

I have done this a hundred times, but everything I tried seem to do nothing. This could be some my fault somehow, but please help. If you need anything more please ask. Regards

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("bro");
    $("#login").click(function () {
        console.log("hi");
        var name = $('#uname').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        console.log(name);
        console.log(password);
        $.ajax({
            url:"login-check.php",
            data: {name:name, password:password},
            dataType:"text",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                if(data === "1" || data === "2"){
                    alert(data);
                    console.log("hello");
                    window.open('index.php','_self');
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Form Code -->
<div class = "container">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Please Fill the form to Sign up</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Username:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type = "username" class = "form-control" name = "uname" id = "uname" placeholder = "username" required autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type = "password" class = "form-control" name = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name = "login" id="login">Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>

     Click here to clean <a href = "logout.php" tite = "Logout">Session.

</div>
```

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6S1Z.png)
[image: network logs]

Comment: But this wouldn't make any sense. I have not associated any action with form.

Comment: I deleted my comment and added ab answer to better explain, this is definitely your issue

Comment: tried moving it outside the form. Still the same problem

Comment: Solved by adding type=button with button. Thanks DelightedD0D.

Comment: dont forget to choose an answer to close the question if the issue is resolved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your button is inside the `form` tag and it does not have a `type` attribute, it is acting as a submit button and submitting the form before the ajax is called (default form method is GET by the way)

Details:

- By default, forms that dont explicitly set a `method` attribute are
  submitted using the `GET` method
- By default, any `button` that is inside a `form` tag that doesnt explicitly set the `type` attribute will be set to `type="submit"`
- Because you do not set either attribute in your `html`, when you click the button, it submits your form using the GET method before your click handler is triggered to call the ajax

#### To correct this there are 3 options:

1. explicitly declare `type="button"` on the button (this is what I would do)
2. call `e.preventDefault` at the top of your click handler to cancel the default behaviour of submitting the actual form
3. move the button outside of the `form` tag (you say you tried this without success, but it does work [see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/unzjakt0/49/) so I imagine you didnt move it quite far enough)

#### Additonally:

As Terry mentions in the comments, you should also explicitly set the `action` and `method` attributes on your form like:

```
<form action="login-check.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

This will ensure that the login works even if the user has javascript disabled and is good practice in general.

Comment: Yup it works. Thanks for your answer. But could you explain the issue in detail please. It would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When the `action` and `method` attributes are not specified, [the browser assumes the action is the page itself, and the method is `GET`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534300/where-does-the-form-submit-to-if-there-is-no-action-specified). And since your button has no `type="button"` attribute, it is treated as a submit button (that is the default role of `<button>` elements). By setting the button to `type="button"`, you effectively prevent the form from being submitted. However, it is still considered good practice to use method POST as an attribute for login forms.

Comment: @Terry beat me to it in their comment but I'be updated my answer to include the details :)

Comment: Would be nice to encourage OP to explicitly specify the form action and method attributes tho ;) there are users, even though in very small numbers, that have JS disabled—the form should call a script (itself or another one) that can perform the login server-side, too, without the need of AJAX :)

Comment: @Terry indeed, added ty:)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
method:"POST",
```

It should be:

```
type: "POST",
```

The definition of type of data is:

```
contentType: "text/plain",
```

EDIT: Full code of the ajax call

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&password=' + password;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"login-check.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            if(data === "1" || data === "2"){
                alert(data);
                console.log("hello");
                window.open('index.php','_self');
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you try this? `var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&password=' + password;` and then `data: dataString,`

Comment: @DelightedD0D type is an alias of method and it works on older versions, so it could be an older version that's not getting the method parameter and ignoring it and using get instead.

Comment: Granted, but the submission of any ajax request could never result in the get parameter being *visible in the browser's URL bar*. The fact that the OP shows a screenshot of just that shows that the AJAX is not being called at all and that the actual form is being submitted directly

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is in the definition of your ajax call.
I would suggest to pass a json object like so:

var obj = { username: un, password: pwd };

Then you can pass this object to the call by stringifying it:

dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(obj)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just added a console log image. Ajax call comes later in function. The log commands are not working. Which are before ajax call. So this cannot be the case. Furthermore I have used this method of sending variables in ajax. They can be accessed in php file using $_POST["var"]; method. as key value so this is also not a problem.

Comment: `data: {name:name, password:password},` is perfectly valid

Comment: Is the javascript loaded in the page together with the HTML

Comment: If you console logs are not executing the JS code may not be loaded on the page