# How to process two forms on a page in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

When processing two forms on a page how do I prevent `Undefined Index` for a variable that has not been submitted?

I have a page with two forms and I am trying to send one of the forms to the server, but I keep getting variables from the other form as an undefined index.

```
<form id="dassets" class="d-none" action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label class="medium my-2" for="assetType">Type</label>
    <input class="form-control my-2" name="coinName" id="assetType" type="text" placeholder="Card Selected" /readonly>
  </div>

  <div class="col px-0">
    <!-- Get current BTC value in dollars -->
    <div id="dataBTC" class="text-primary"></div>

    <label class="medium my-2">Coin value</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="coin-value">BTC</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" aria-label="BTC" aria-describedby="coin-value">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col px-0">
      <label for="file01" class="my-2">Please upload a very clear photo of the payment receipt/gift card where necessary</label>

      <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <label for="file01">Upload a file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="file01">
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BTC">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded px-3 mt-3" value="Trade" name="submit"/>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Card trade -->
<div class="col-xl-7 card-body d-none" id="dock">
```

Here is the second form; I added a hidden field to distinguish them:

```
<form id="amazonForm" class="d-none" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label for="cardType">Type</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="typeAmazon" type="text" placeholder="Card Selected" name="ca2rdType" readonly/>
  </div>
  <div class="col px-0">
    <label for="ctry" class="my-2">Country</label>
    <select id="ctryAmazon" class="form-control" name="country">
      <option selected>USD</option>
      <option>EUR</option>
      <option>CAD</option>
      <option>GDP</option>
      <option>CHF</option>
      <option>AUD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col px-0">
    <label for="country" class="my-3">Select Gift Card Type</label>

    <!--Amazon Gift Cards -->
    <div id="amazonUsa" class="d-none">

      <!-- Cash Receipt -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="amazonCash">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="amazonCash">Cash Receipt</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Debit Receipt -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="amazonDebit">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="amazonDebit">Debit Receipt</label>
      </div>

      <!-- No Receipt -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="noReceipt">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="noReceipt">No Receipt</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Ecode -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="eCode">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="eCode">Ecode</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Physical -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="physical">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="physical">Physical</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Large card -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="largecard">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="largecard">Large Card</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col d-md-flex justify-content-between px-0">
        <div>
          <label for="amount" class="my-3">Input card value amount</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="amount" type="number" placeholder="Enter an amount"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="equivalent" class="my-3">Equivalent in Naira</label>
          <input class="form-control text-success" id="cashout" type="text" placeholder="Cashout in Naira" readonly/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col px-0">
      <label for="file02" class="my-2">Please upload a very clear photo of the payment receipt/giftcard</label>

      <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <label for="file01">Upload a file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="file02">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="GTC">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded px-3 mt-3" value="Trade" name="submit_2"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: add your code from process.php to get clear idea

Comment: Have you a closing </form> in the first form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at **SERVER** side (i.e. process.php):

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'BTC') {
        //action for BTChere
    } else if ($_POST['action'] == 'GTC') {
        //action for GTC
    } else {
        //invalid action!
    }
```

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547848/5803974)

**Still you have issue then try AJAX.**

***Also,***

You miss **action** attribute from second form (it's empty).

If you want to submit to **process.php** then add in second form (No need to check action again)

or other file then add respective path (Need to check action i.e. $_POST['action'] is BTC or GTC).

By default,empty action submit redirect to same file.

[Check this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5534300/5803974)

Hope you get idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `if` statement in your PHP to check if your variables exist before you use them, and if they are undefined then you can deal with that error in a cleaner fashion.

Comment: I have validated my input. can you please show this with a block of code? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Give each submit button a different name i.e.

```
<input name='form1' type='summit' value='submit'>
<input name='form2' type='summit' value='submit'>
```

In php you can then use

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'form1' ) {
     // do form1 stuff
} else if( isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'form2' ) {
     // do form 2 stuff
}
```

Comment: this didn't work. I still get the form field from the other form .

Comment: The web page is working as expected. The page submits any number of forms on it all at once, not just the button you clicked. It is up to you, the programmer, how to handle the data being sent and how to act upon the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the php block, also are you checking isset("submit")? then since you know the particular action that was performed also check the isset the variables too.